# How do I stop Visual Studio 2015 connecting to every connection string on project load?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

When trying to open a solution which contains a large number of connection strings, Visual Studio 2015 attempts to connect to each and every one when loading the project.

Each developer on our team uses a local instance of SQL Server during development. This instance can have multiple copies of our main database which include different levels of migrations - we're a small team, so often end up switching tasks half-way through.

To allow for this, we have a number of connection strings which are machine-specific, and when creating our DbContext we use the machine name to determine which connection string to use:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- Steve -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_LT4" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=LT4\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  <!-- Sean -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_DESKTOP-UQV58RL" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-UQV58RL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  <!-- Sarah -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_Dev-3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=Dev-3\;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  <!-- Graham -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_lt5" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  <add name="MachineConnection_graham-surface3" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  <add name="MachineConnection_graham-pc-10" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  <!-- Alex -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_Dev9" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=Dev9;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

  <!-- Reuben -->
  <add name="MachineConnection_ReubenPC" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=REUBENPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Our context is then initialised like so:

```
public class TTDataContext : DbContext
{
    public const string CacheKey = "dbContext";

    public TTDataContext()
        : base(SqlConnections.GetConnectionStringName())
    {
    }

    ...

}
```

And uses this to help:

```
public class SqlConnections
{
    private const string DefaultConnectionStringName = "DefaultConnection";

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the name of the connection string to use.
    /// This attempts to find a machine-specific connection string e.g. MachineConnection_LT4, and falls back to
    /// the default connection string if a machine-specific connection string is not found
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetConnectionStringName()
    {
        // This enables a connection string to be completely overridden in the cloud service configuration
        try
        {
            var cloudConnectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("TTDatabaseConnectionString");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cloudConnectionString)) return cloudConnectionString;
        }
        catch
        {
            // Deliberately empty - an exception will be thrown if not running on AppFabric
        }

        string machineSpecificConnectionStringName = string.Format("MachineConnection_{0}", Environment.MachineName);
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[machineSpecificConnectionStringName] == null
                   ? DefaultConnectionStringName
                   : machineSpecificConnectionStringName;
        return connectionString;
    }
}
```

When Visual Studio 2015 loads the project (either initally, or on changing Git branch), it tries to establish connections to every single connection string specified in the list (confirmed by removing all but 1 of them) and as they're all local to each relevant machine it stops responding until the connection times out, throwing this error:

[image: SQL Connection Error]

Visual Studio 2013 had no issue with this set-up. Is there a way to persuade Visual Studio 2015 to behave in the same way?

Comment: it's hard to believe that Visual Studio 2015 does such stupid thing. Very bad design. This should be sent to VS team for an explanation as well as a fix in future versions.

Comment: Weird behavior. Couldn't reproduce it though. I copied one of your connection strings but it didn't try to connect and time out when I re-opened the project. It only happened when I manually clicked on Refresh in the Server Explorer. Maybe there is some external plugin forcing an auto-refresh?

Comment: Thanks @VolkanPaksoy - it does appear to be more prevalent when changing branch and VS reloads the projects. Just tried making sure the Server Explorer window was closed and restarting before loading again and it still happens - Server Explorer afterwards shows each connection with a red 'X' next to it so it's clearly trying to connect and realising the connection isn't available. I'm going to try disabling all plugins next and see if that changes anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was caused by an extension - specifically the Karma Test Adapter (version 1.1.3) which seems to automatically run some code on project load.

Disabling this extension solved the issue.